# $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\cos \phi} \cos(\sin \phi)\, d\phi}{5-4\cos(\theta-\phi)}$ , how do I solve those integrals?

Tags: integration

how to solve the following integrals:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\cos \phi} \cos(\sin \phi)\,d\phi}{5-4\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

and 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\cos \phi} \sin(\sin \phi)\, d\phi}{5-4\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

The stuff that I was "taught" in class is Fourier Transform, method of residues, Dirichlet problem for a circle and the upper half plane.
In anyways, even if complex numbers are being used, the final answer for each integral should be a real function of $\theta$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You mway want to use the fact that $e^{\cos \phi} \cos(\sin \phi) = \mathrm{Re} \,e^{e^{i\phi}}$.